# PyQt5 - Default datetime to QDateTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to add into a QDateTimeEdit() a default date from now + 7 days.

I find the function setDateTime I can't make

```
dateTimeBegin.setDateTime(datetime.now+7)
```

or somethings like that

Hope you can help me.

Thanks per advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
currentTime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
dateTimeBegin.setDateTime(currentTime.addDays(7))
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lblCurrentDateTime   = QLabel()
        self.lblDateTimeEdit = QLabel()
        btn = QPushButton("DateTime + 7 days")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.editDateDay)

        lblCurrentDateTime.setText(QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss'))

        self.dateTimeBegin = QDateTimeEdit()
        self.dt = self.dateTimeBegin.dateTime().currentDateTime()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(lblCurrentDateTime)
        lay.addWidget(self.lblDateTimeEdit)
        lay.addWidget(btn)

    def editDateDay(self):
        self.dateTimeBegin.setDateTime(self.dt.addDays(7))
        self.dt = self.dt.addDays(7)
        currentTime = self.dateTimeBegin.dateTime().toString('yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss')
        self.lblDateTimeEdit.setText(self.dateTimeBegin.dateTime().toString('yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss'))

if __name__ =="__main__":
    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot !